# MongoDB - When to add SubDocuments and when to Ref

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Im using MongoDB for storing information for a nodeJS application and a doubt came to my mind, after finding that it is possible to use ObjectID to [ref](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) another document. As it is known, MongoDB is a no-SQL db, so there is no need for consistency whatsoever and information can be repeated.

So, lets say, I have a collection for users and one of their field values is 'friends', which is an array of this user friends (another users). What is the best practice, saving all the user info there (thus repeating the same thing over and over again throughout the DB) or saving only the ObjectID of the friendUser (makes way more sense to me, but it sounds kinda SQL mindset). I'm not really getting when should I use each of the options, so a professional opinion would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To model relationships between connected data, you can reference a document or embed it in another document as a subdocument.
2. Referencing a document does not create a “real” relationship between these two documents as does with a relational database.
3. Referencing documents is also known as normalization. It is good for data consistency but creates more queries in your system.
4. Embedding documents is also known as denormalization.
5. The benefit of Embedding approach is getting all the data you need about a document and it’s sub-document(s) with a single query. Therefore, this approach is very fast. The drawback is that data may not stay as consistent in the database.

**Important**

1. If one document is to be used by many documents then better create a referenced doc.

   i. Will Save Space.

   ii. if any change required, we will have to update only the referenced doc 
       instead of updating many docs.
2. Create sub doc(embedded)

   i. If another document is not dependent on the subdocument.

Source: https://vegibit.com/mongoose-relationships-tutorial/

**Recommended reading:**

> MongoDB Applied Design Patterns by Rick Copeland
>   [To Embed or Reference](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mongodb-applied-design/9781449340056/ch01.html)

Comment: Makes total sense, thanks a lot for the kind and incisive explanation!!

Comment: I am glad it helped  :)